# Setting Trace32 in standby mode

Tags: lauterbach, tricore

I would like to know the various setting for T32, my target board currently Tricore 377, As part of test, we do IGN cycle at various interval. We would like Trace32 to continue monitoring after soft reset, but currently after soft reset, Trace32 goes “System Down” instead of going “StandBy” . This issue is intermittent.

Comment: If you are using multiple PowerView instances, make sure that SystemMode synchronization is enabled in the SYnch window. Also make sure that you are using the latest TRACE32 software release version. If that doesn't help, please contact Lauterbach support here: https://support.lauterbach.com/new-ticket